# splitting string using RE library in Python, how to keep punctuation marks and other non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to simulate the compiler's scanner and parser phases. I managed to split using

```
    re.findall(r"[\w,.,\"]+",file)
```

and if the file contains:

```
INT x;
READ x;
x := (x+1)*x;
WRITE x
```

that is the result:

```
['INT', 'x', 'READ', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', 'x', 'WRITE', 'x']
```

However I need the ; and + and () and so on... how do I split the words but keep the characters?? thank you

This should be the output:

```
['INT', 'x', ';', 'READ', 'x', ';', 'x', ':=',  '(','x', '+', '1', ')', '*', 'x', ';', 'WRITE', 'x']
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting to get from that input? Could you please provide an example of what the desired output should be?

Comment: why do you cancel the parentheses ? there are useful for correct parsing

Comment: sorry I forgot... it's correct now

Comment: Must you use regex? If not then you might be better off building your code based on a parser such as http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (almost correct) code should be:

```
import re

source = """
INT x;
READ x;
x := (x+1)*x;
WRITE x
"""
print(re.findall(r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', source)
```

Output:

```
['INT', 'x', ';', 'READ', 'x', ';', 'x', ':=', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')*', 'x', ';', 'WRITE', 'x']
```

However, as long as you don't explicitely define all operators of your language, there is no solution to distinguish a correct multi-char operator (e.g. `:=`) from a concatenated sequence of single-char operators (e.g. `)*`. So, using a true parser would be much more easier for such as task.

EDIT (after comment):

The regex basically searches for 2 types of sequences: either one-or-more consecutive alphanumeric characters (represented by `\w+`) or one-or-more consecutive characters that are non-alphanumeric and non-space (represented by `[^\w\s]+`).

Comment: thank you that did work :)... if you could explain the "\w+|[^\s\w]+" part i would be very grateful (i like understanding what i'm writing)

Comment: thank you.. I tried it exactly as you said but the ")*" stay together still, I think any nonalphanumeric next to each other will be considered one expression (same with ":=" but that one we need it)... I tried "\w+|[^\s\w]" without + and it separates both expressions ":", "="... do you have a solution

Comment: Read carefully the last sentence of my answer before the 'EDIT' line: there is no way for a regex to know that ':=' is correct and ')*' is incorrect. You have to explicitely list all the operators of your langage, which is much easier with a true parser than with a regex engine

Comment: ":=|\w+|[^\w\s]" this worked... thank you so much for your help.. this is a project for my Compiler course so a true parser would defeat the purpose... I just wanted to do the best i could and also understand it not just copy..

Comment: OK, I guess you've learnt some interesting stuff by asking your question on SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
import re

test_str = "INT x; READ x; x := (x+1)*x; WRITE x"
test_reg_pat = "([A-Z]+)|([x])|([^ ])"

test_list = re.findall(test_reg_pat,test_str)


ret_list = []

for sub_list in test_list:
  for elem in sub_list:
    if elem != '':
      ret_list.append(elem)


print(ret_list)
```

Where output of `ret_list` is:

```
['INT', 'x', ';', 'READ', 'x', ';', 'x', ':', '=', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')', '*', 'x', ';', 'WRITE', 'x']
```

There may be a way to do this purely with regex without having to process `test_list` into `ret_list` how I did it. Biggest issue is that using `re.findall()` with groups (what I used in my pattern) is that it will return a sub-list with any matches to the group, which looks like this:

```
[('INT', '', ''), ('', 'x', ''), ('', '', ';'), ('READ', '', ''), ('', 'x', ''), ('', '', ';'), ('', 'x', ''), ('', '', ':'), ('', '', '='), ('', '', '('), ('', 'x', ''), ('', '', '+'), ('', '', '1'), ('', '', ')'), ('', '', '*'), ('', 'x', ''), ('', '', ';'), ('WRITE', '', ''), ('', 'x', '')]
```

Hope it helps - if you need it with purely regex let me know and I can see if I can work something out!

Answer (score 0):

You could try being very explicit about what you want to match where `input` is your input string:

```
re.findall(r"\w+|:=|[\w()*+;]", input)
```

This should give the exact output that you are looking for:

```
['INT', 'x', ';', 'READ', 'x', ';', 'x', ':=', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')', '*', 'x', ';', 'WRITE', 'x']
```

Comment: actually it worked to an extent so thank you, but not completely:     ['INT', 'x', ';', 'READ', 'x', ';', 'x', ':=', '(x+1)*x;', 'WRITE', 'x']

Comment: The output that I shared here came directly from `findall` with that input. I tested this on both Python 2.7 and 3.6, so I'm not sure why you are seeing a different result.

Comment: @MNS: This is what I meant in my answer: you have to explicitely list ALL operators of the language, single-char ops (*, +, -, /, (, ), etc), double-char ops (:=, +=, -=; etc), triple-char ops (if any) and put them all as alternative sub-expressions in your final regex. This is not impossible but it is not a job that should be done with a regex.